# Cordova/phonegap crashes after taking a picture with camera.getPicture

Tags: android, cordova

I'm developing an app using Cordova 2.6 and I have a problem using the camera.getPicture function on older phones (that don't have gigs of memory).

When the app opens the camera, it (the app) is moved to the background. Then Android's Garbage Collector kicks in and kills the app. So when I've taken my picture and it is returned to my app it crashes (Force Close) with a null pointer exception.

The problem is well known but is not documented as a 'quirck'.

Here's someone else with the same problem:
[Camera example from the docs page fails on android 2.3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583832/camera-example-from-the-docs-page-fails-on-android-2-3-x)

The biggest problem I have is that I can't detect this. If I could I might give the user a warning but now it just force closes and ruins the experience.

EDIT: here's the exception from logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=null} to activity
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a custom camera plugin and save your image to a set image file. When the app reloads may it be a crash or a forced closed due to memory check for the existence of that file and continue.

This would require some saving a state before the camera was called so that the app could reinitialize to handle image.

The place I believe to put a check for a previouly taken image could be in the onCreate method in your main class or onActivityResult in the camera plugin

Here is a similar thread [Taking a picture from the camera fails 20% of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544992/taking-a-picture-from-the-camera-fails-20-of-the-time/11546276#11546276)

Bellow is code for is what I have started on this but handling all the different camera bugs can be problematic, ie [Android ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910608/android-action-image-capture-intent)

To get this to work for this task you need to use the getExternalSaveFile method to save your file and then modify your oncreate / onactivityresult to handle the restarting of the app.

Here is Javascript to the call plugin

```
        CameraSW.takePhoto("onPhotoURISuccess");
    //Then, to get the location of the photo after you take it and load the page again
    var imgPath = CameraSW.getPhotoUri();
    console.log("capturePhotoEdit: imgPath " + imgPath);


function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {

}
```

Register your main app so you can reach the functions in javascript

```
    static public Uri getCameraSaveFile(Context context, String directory,
        String basename, boolean fixed, String ext) {
    String fileName =   your_app.getImageFileName(basename, fixed,ext);
    //"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,
            "Image capture by camera");

    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

    Uri imageUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

    Log.i("MainActivity",
            "new image uri to string is " + imageUri.toString());

    Log.i("MainActivity", "new image path is " + imageUri.getPath());
    return imageUri;
}

static public Uri getExternalSaveFile(String directory, String basename,
        boolean fixed, String ext) {
    try {
        Uri newImageUri = null;
        if (ext == null)
            ext = "jpg";
        String dir_name = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/" + directory + "/";
        File path = new File(dir_name);
        Log.e(TAG, "getExternalSaveFile path = "
                +Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/"
                + directory + "/");
 // crashing here ? wtf
        if (!path.exists()) {
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, "getExternalSaveFile: mkdirs" + dir_name);
                path.mkdirs();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG,
                        "getExternalSaveFile: mkdir error" + e.getMessage());

            }
        }
        if (!path.isDirectory()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getExternalSaveFile: file is not directory"
                    + dir_name);
            return null;
        }
        boolean setWritable = false;

        setWritable = path.setWritable(true, false);
        if (!setWritable) {
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "getExternalSaveFile Failed to set the file to writable");
        }
        File file = new File(path, your_app.getImageFileName(basename, fixed,
                ext));

        newImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        Log.i(TAG, "getExternalSaveFile new image uri to string is "
                + newImageUri.toString());

        Log.i(TAG,
                "getExternalSaveFile new image path is "
                        + newImageUri.getPath());
        return newImageUri;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getExternalSaveFile: main error" + e.getMessage());

    }
    return null;
}

static public String getImageFileName(String basename, boolean fixed,
        String ext) {
    String file = null;
    if (fixed) {
        file = basename + "." + ext;
    } else {
        file = basename + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + ext;
    }
    return file;
}

public void takePhoto(final String callback) {
    Log.v(TAG, "takePhoto: Starting takePhoto: " + callback);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    Log.v(TAG, "takePhoto: new intent");
    //Uri path = getExternalSaveFile("your_app", "question_", true, "jpg");
    Uri path = getCameraSaveFile(this,"your_app", "question_", true, "jpg");
    if (path == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "takePhoto: path is not writable or can not be found");
        // should pass error on ward to phonegap
        return;
    }
    image_uri  = path.toString();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, path);
    Log.v(TAG, "takePhoto: getExternalSaveFile");

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    // Intent intent = new
    // Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
    // Uri.fromFile(new File(folderPath, filePath)));
    if (your_app.webView != null && your_app.webView.pluginManager != null) {

        CameraSWPlugin plugin = (CameraSWPlugin)your_app.webView.pluginManager.getPlugin("CameraSW");
        if (plugin == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "takePhoto: startActivityForResult: plugin CameraSWPlugin null make sure plugin is listed in config.xml <plugin name=\"CameraSW\" value=\"com.your_app.your_app.CameraSWPlugin\" />");
            throw new NullPointerException("takePhoto: startActivityForResult: plugin CameraSWPlugin null make sure plugin is listed in config.xml <plugin name=\"CameraSW\" value=\"com.your_app.your_app.CameraSWPlugin\" />");
        } else {
            plugin.setPath(path);
            plugin.setSuccess_callback(callback);
        startActivityForResult(
                plugin,
                intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
        Log.v(TAG, "takePhoto: startActivityForResult");
        }
    } else {
        // should not happen
        Log.v(TAG, "webView or Pluginmanager not read");
    }
}

public String getPhotoUri() {
    return image_uri;
//      return Uri.fromFile(new File(folderPath, filePath)).toString();
}
```

The plugin file CameraSWPlugin.java

```
package com.your_app.your_app;

import static com.your_app.your_app.CommonUtilities.TAKE_PICTURE;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import static com.your_app.your_app.CommonUtilities.TAG;
/**
 *   I did not include the    
 * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
 */
public class CameraSWPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("echo")) {
            String message = args.getString(0); 
            your_app.invalidate();
            this.echo(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void echo(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }



@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.v(TAG, "Photo onActivityResult requestCode = " + requestCode + " resultCode = " + resultCode + " data = " + data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                //Do whatever you need to do when the camera returns
                //This is after the picture is already saved, we return to the page
                if (this.path != null) {
                    // 

                    try {
                        this.sendJavascript(path.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult: path json error " + e.getMessage());                  
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v(TAG, "onActivityResult: path was not set " + requestCode);                    
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            Log.v(TAG, "Something strange happened... " + requestCode);
            break;
    }
}
private String success_callback = null;
private Uri path = null;
public String getSuccess_callback() {
    return success_callback;
}

public void setSuccess_callback(String success_callback) {
    this.success_callback = success_callback;
}

public  void sendJavascript( JSONObject _json )
{

String _d =  "javascript:"+this.success_callback+"(" + _json.toString() + ")";
      Log.v(TAG + ":sendJavascript", _d);

      if (this.success_callback != null ) {
          this.webView.sendJavascript( _d );
      }
}


public  void sendJavascript( String _json )
{

String _d =  "javascript:"+this.success_callback+"(" + JSONObject.quote(_json) + ")";
      Log.v(TAG + ":sendJavascript", _d);

      if (this.success_callback != null ) {
          this.webView.sendJavascript( _d );
      }
}

public void setPath(Uri path) {
    this.path = path;   
}

}
```

And be sure to add to your config.xml

```
 <plugin name="CameraSW" value="com.your_app.your_app.CameraSWPlugin" />
```

Comment: forgot to mention I'm working with 2.8.0 ... so not sure if this will run in 2.6

Answer (score 0):

For ME there is a bug in the camera plugin.  I fixed it for MY situation.  This may or may not apply to yours.

Scenario:

1. Using a tablet where the NATIVE CAMERA APP rotates to Landscape when it launches.
2. My app is running in portrait.  Because of this it needs to saveInstance var's and reload them.

What I found and what I fixed:

First look at ProcessResultFromCamera function -> these lines:

```
        String sourcePath = (this.allowEdit && this.croppedUri != null) ?
                this.croppedFilePath :
                this.imageFilePath;
```

It's using imageUri but saving imageFilePath?  Maybe this is intended maybe not.

I added a quick debug helper class to push out Toasts.  I added Toasts all throughout CameraLauncher.java.

I looked at onSaveInstanceState and noticed a couple things:

1. imageFilePath is not being stored anywhere in onSaveInstanceState so when the Activity recreates itself...the imageFilePath that was initially created is now null.  This imageFilePath is what's passed into ExifInterface.  If you note ABOVE...sourcePath is assigned to imageFilePath.

This would explain why we get the "filename cannot be null" as that specific exception is thrown in ExifInterface.java I believe.

```
                **_exif.createInFile(sourcePath);_**  <<---- sourcePath is null
                exif.readExifData();
                rotate = exif.getOrientation();
```

```
        if (this.**imageUri** != null) {
            state.putString(IMAGE_URI_KEY, this.**imageFilePath**);
        }
```

The Fix??

Update imageUri in onSaveInstanceState.  Add imageFileName to onSaveInstanceState.

Add imageFileName to onRestore

here's the actual code to update/add in onSaveInstanceState:

```
        if (this.imageUri != null) {
            state.putString(IMAGE_URI_KEY, String.valueOf(this.imageUri));
        }

        if (this.imageFilePath != null) {
            state.putString(IMAGE_FILE_PATH_KEY, this.imageFilePath);
        }
```

here's the code to ADD in onRestoreStateForActivityResult:

```
        if (state.containsKey(IMAGE_FILE_PATH_KEY)) {
            this.imageFilePath = state.getString(IMAGE_FILE_PATH_KEY);
        }
```